TonConnect sendTransaction - mobile app issue
I have implemented the connection of the user's wallet to the site via TonConnect ui
The user connects, specifies the amount he wants to invest in the project, sends a request - on desktop and web the request comes perfectly, everything works, but for example in tonkeeper mobile application the request comes and disappears immediately. I suspect that it's the signature, but I can't figure out how to do it. Here is the code of sending, as far as I understand, I need before
    await tonConnectUI.sendTransaction(transaction, {
        modals: ['before', 'success', 'error'],  
        notifications: ['before', 'success', 'error']  
    });   

send a request for a signature, but I don't understand at all how this is set up and should be, and the documentation is totally confusing to me( Please help me to achieve a successful request on mobile apps.
 const tonConnectUI = new TON_CONNECT_UI.TonConnectUI({
 manifestUrl: 'https://example.com/tonconnect-manifest.json',
 buttonRootId: 'ton-connect' });



async function initiateTransaction(amount) {


 var sm = amount;

 const recipientAddress = 'UQDVqo3lguMUvPwdD6xk7lMz3g_cHFFMhnEO6hI1n2XXLt0I';  
const transaction = {
   validUntil: Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000) + 360,
    messages: [
        {
          address: recipientAddress,
            amount: (amount * 1000000000).toString()  
        }
    ]
};

  try {
    const currentAccount = tonConnectUI.account;
    let json = JSON.stringify(currentAccount);
    var myObj = JSON.parse(json);
    const ad = myObj['address'];
    const nacl = TonWeb.utils.nacl;
    const tonweb = new TonWeb();
    const keyPair = nacl.sign.keyPair();
    let secretKey = keyPair.secretKey;
    let wallet = tonweb.wallet.create({
        publicKey: keyPair.publicKey
    });
    wallet = tonweb.wallet.create({
        address: ad
    });
    secretKey = TonWeb.utils.hexToBytes('1209645867598672398567298346723894769879');
    const address = await wallet.getAddress();
    const address_o = address.toString(true, true, true, false);         

     
  //  $.ajax({
  //       url: "/handler_transaction.php",
  //       type: "post",
  //       dataType: "json",
  //       data: {
  //           "adt": address_o,
        //          "sm": sm,

  //       },
  //       success: function(data) {
       
  //       }
  //   });       
     



    // Отправляем транзакцию с подписанием через TON Connect UI
    const result = await tonConnectUI.sendTransaction(transaction, {
        modals: ['before', 'success', 'error'],  // Модальные окна для отображения        статуса
        notifications: ['before', 'success', 'error']  // Оповещения о статусе
    });

    const someTxData = await myAppExplorerService.getTransaction(result.boc);
    console.log('Текст boc ', someTxData);
    console.log('Транзакция отправлена', result);

    if (result.success) {
        console.log('Транзакция успешно выполнена');
        // const walletInfo = await tonConnectUI.getWalletInfo();
        // const walletAddress = walletInfo.account.address;
        // await updateStaking(walletAddress, amount);
        alert('Транзакция успешно отправлена');
    } else {
        console.error('Транзакция не удалась', result.errorMessage);
        alert('Ошибка отправки транзакции: ' + result.errorMessage);
    }
} catch (error) {
    console.error('Ошибка при отправке транзакции', error);
    alert('Ошибка отправки транзакции: ' + error.message);
}
}`

I've tried everything I can think of, but I'm exhausted.
UPD.
Basically I've done everything as stated in the API documentation - but it still doesn't work via mobile apps.
At the moment it is known that before sending a request for a transaction, I have to send some data (differently in different examples), check it in some way and return bool. I've seen this in several examples from a year ago

are u sure about manifestUrl json data? and be sure manifestUrl  is attach to connection url befor call for opening the wallet

if you make your application with unity make sure that the player setting > managedStrippingLevel to be minimal. otherwise the connection url has missing the manifest Url.
